# Bulletproof and FontSquirrel font-face methods not working in IE10

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9, font-face, internet-explorer-10

First I should mention I'm working on Tumblr so I'm somewhat limited as far as server-side stuff. I know there are a ton of questions on here about @font-face, but I just can't find a solution to getting it to work in IE9 and 10. I was using the FontSquirrel syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('fontname.eot');
    src: url('fontname.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fontname.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fontname.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fontname.svg#FontName') format('svg');
}
```

Until I discovered it wasn't working in Firefox or IE 9/10, so I've been converting over to using base64 encoding, basing it on a FontSquirrel template and encoding the .woff files at base64fonts.com:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontName';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url('fontname.eot');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontName';
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,......) format('woff'),
            url('fontname.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('fontname.svg#FontName') format('svg');
    }
```

(The string of dots representing the giant string of base64 characters). This works great in Chrome and Firefox and seems to work in IE8, but no amount of massaging seems to make IE10 render anything other than an ugly system font.

I've tried single quotes, double quotes, no quotes. I've made sure the .ttf has embeddable permissions. I even tried getting rid of my doctype. I read up on [bulletproof](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) syntax and tried these [examples](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/39519/webfontsdemo/index.html). When I load that example page in IE10, all but a couple of them render fine; but using the same syntax on my page isn't working.

If you want to peek at my monstrous code it's at gist.github.com/neuraldamage/5307289 (as you see I have tried plenty of fonts) and the site in question is at neuraldamage.tumblr.com. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Wondering if this is a problem with IE 9/10 not liking Tumblr static files? Real examples of my code from gist.github.com/neuraldamage/5307289:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gudea';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/cDgmgcczj/gudea-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/cDgmgcczj/gudea-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/Qkvmgcd2c/gudea-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/LIamgcd1z/gudea-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/K3Nmgcd0s/gudea-regular-webfont.svg#Gudea') format('svg');
}
```

Had to truncate the base64 encoding to get this to fit:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FunctionPro';
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/OXFmhmdhl/functionpro-light-webfont.eot');
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'FunctionPro';
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGvkAB......FQNRtdAAA=) format('woff'),
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/8SEmhmdin/functionpro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://static.tumblr.com/6u5yyqj/vIVmhmdi7/functionpro-light-webfont.svg#FunctionPro') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: I always use FontSquirrel's Webfont generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) for @font-face.

Comment: Alas, that's what I've been using (just a cleaned up version with extra spaces etc. removed) but it won't work in 9/10.

Comment: Are you limited to @font-face? I use Google Webfonts for my Tumblr (font is Lato, used `<link>`) and it works fine. I also used FontSquirrel for my portfolio site and that works fine too in IE10.

Comment: This is probably font-specific, so please specify a real font with which the problem occurs and the origin of the font, preferably with a URL of a minimal demo.

Comment: This is happening with all the fonts on my site, whether I put them in the former syntax or the latter. For instance: Asap, Florin Sans, Function Pro, Gudea, Nimbus Sans Novus, Thirsty Script. Some were free and some I purchased from various sites, mostly FontSpring. The files are then uploaded to tumblr. I'll add a real example of the syntax above.

Comment: Also re: Google Webfonts, I'm limited by wanting to use fonts that I've purchased.

Answer (score 0):

The final html markup on your page is showing two DOCTYPE's, only one DOCTYPE is allowed and it must occur before any elements. When you have an error as critical as this, IE usually will get all confused and fail at other parsing too.

Same as w3c validation: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fneuraldamage.tumblr.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Although its not essential to fix all w3c errors to debug this issue I feel this one is preventing an answer being found or causing the issue in the first place.

Line 1

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>**
```

line 13

```
**<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">**
```

I would choose to keep the html5 doctype (first one) if possible